# What are the left over Clusters for?

Tags: saints-row-iv

I've been nearing the end of the story quests, and decided to start sweeping up the last few sides/activities/collectibles, etc. As part of that, I've just finished gathering the last Data Cluster. Got the achievement and everything. Similarly, I've picked up every super power upgrade I can buy. Got that achievement too.

But, I still have 190 clusters left over. And this seems... strange. There are a fixed number of clusters, and a fixed number of things to spend them on, so am I missing something? Is there something else to spend them on? Or are there just a hundred and ninety more Data Clusters than you need to pick up?

Comment: Well... I was just thinking about asking if there were enough clusters to buy all the upgrades. This is convenient! :D

Answer (score 9):

I can think of two reasons:

1. By making the number of available clusters comfortably larger than the amount needed to upgrade everything, they can add new superpowers or enhancements to the existing ones via DLC without having to redo the map and figure out where to put additional clusters.
2. It means players can max out their superpowers without having to pixel-hunt the entire map to find out where they missed a cluster. Probably an important consideration given that they're not marked on the main city map and the minimap's range is pretty limited...

This is conjecture on my part, obviously , but I think they make sense.

Comment: Actually, they *are* marked on the main city map. All the collectibles are. You just need to cycle the map's display mode to "collectibles" first. Makes it near-trivial to grab them all.

Comment: @BillyMailman Isn't that an ability you need to unlock first? Or atleast see them for once.

Comment: The minimap thing at least requires an unlock to do something for Matt Miller.

Comment: @Lyrion I *think* you might need the collectible finder for it, yeah, though the thing unlocks so early in SR4 I honestly didn't even check if the main map showed the collectibles without it.

Comment: I think the first is more likely. They may have more DLC that adds more elements or adds additional upgrades. There's definitely going to be DLC though.